# Possible to use the same icon to open and close a modal?

Tags: css, css-transitions, bootstrap-modal

I'm wondering whether I can use the "same" icon (or something that looks the same) that triggers a full-screen, semi-transparent Bootstrap modal (that I have customized) to pop up and then close it with an icon that is in the same location.

However, say it is initially a hamburger icon on the normal page, when I click the icon to pop up the modal menu, it is now under the modal. Is there a way to have it stay on top of even a modal? I tried z-index but I couldn't get it to work.

The tricky thing for me is that I wanted to have the icon transition from a hamburger to an X and then vice versa when it closed: http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/navicon-transformicons/

Initially I was hoping I could get the icon to transition and then somehow set the icon to layer on top of everything, including modals.

Any ideas or suggestions would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this with z-index. However, z-index only works with elements that have "position" set to something other than "static" (the default). Try adding `position: relative` to your open / close button and hopefully then you should be able to use z-index to keep the button in front of the overlay.

There's a good reference with more info about z-index on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

Comment: hmm, I added a fixed position and high z-index to the navbar (which is what I want to lay on top of everything) and then the modal has a relative position but it's still not working...

Comment: Could it be a problem with nesting? If the button is inside an element that is behind the overlay then it can't be in front of the overlay, regardless of what z-index you put on it. The CSS Tricks page explains this in greater detail.